# where does neo4j save its data?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, redis, neo4j

I read some where that it is better to use Redis as cache server,because Redis holds the data in memory,so if you are going to save lots of data,Redis is not a good choice. Redis is good for keeping temporary data.now my question is:

1.where do rest of databases (especially neo4j and sql server) save data?
Don't they save data in memory?

if no,so where they save them?

if yes,why do we use them for saving lots of data?

2."It is better to save indices/relationships in neo4j and data in mysql,and retrieve the index from neo4j and then take the data related to the index from mysql" (I have read it some where),is this because neo4j has the same problem as Redis does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Neo4J and SQL Server both store data on the file system.  However, both also implement caching strategies.  I am not an expert on the caching in these databases.  Usually you can expect recently accessed data to be cached and data that has not been accessed for a while to fall out of the cache.  If the DB needs to get something that is in the cache, it can avoid hits to the file system. Neo4j saves data in a subfolder called "data" by default.  This linke may help you find the location of a SQL Server database: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206993.aspx
2. This will depend a lot on your specific use-case and the required performance characteristics.  My gut feeling is to put data in one or the other based on some initial performance tests.  Split the data up if it solves some specific problem.